# node.js and mongoose: how to call 2 nested callbacks methods to save into collection and nested list?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm building a node.js app using mongoDB.
I need to create a book object, save it and also add it to the books list of a user.
I then need to have one "save" for the book and then a second one for the user (for which the books list has been updated).

I do something like:

```
book = new Book();   // I'm using moogoose 
book.title = req.params.title
book.save(function(err){
  if(!err){
    jsonObj = {"title":book.title};
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
    res.write(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
    res.end();

    // Add book in user things list
    user.books.push(book);
    user.save(function(error){
      if(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify({ "error" : "internal error" }));
      }
    });
  } else {
    jsonObj = { "error" : "internal error while saving book" };
    res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
    res.write(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
    res.end();
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
});
```

It seems that sometimes the book is saved in DB and not saved into the user's books list, and sometimes it's the other way round. I'm not that familiar with asynch callback method (nested on top of that...).

I surely do something wrong... What's the best way to do this ?

Comment: If an error occurs saving the book then your book will not be added to the user list.

Comment: @Raynos, but sometimes the book is saved on its own but not saved in the user's  books list.

Comment: that's what I said. The book can be saved on its own, but a different error occurs stopping the book from being added to the user list. So try `console.log(err)` in your else block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too sure myself but I think Mongo is saving two different objects of book because it considers them two different objects (even for Javascript the book in the user array and the object both are pointing towards the same thing)..

You'll be better of saving the Book object in Mongo. Get the _ObjectID (generated by MongoDB) and save that to user books array.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes change your code to:

```
} else {
  console.log("error saving book : ", err);
  jsonObj = { "error" : "internal error while saving book" };
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'application/json'});
  res.write(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
  res.end();
}
```

Comment: @Raynos... hmm in fact I think this is my understanding of Mongoose which is not correct (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html), it seems I end up creating 2 differents book in my case (ie I want to create on on its own and then one in the user). I am not sure this is the good approach.